# Question marks in regular expressions: what do they mean where they are used here?

Tags: sql, regex, perl

Could someone explain what they mean where they are being used?

```
if(m/DROP TABLE IF EXISTS \`?$tableName\`?/ || m/CREATE TABLE \`?$tableName\`?/){
           $inside=1
};
```

-Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `?` makes the character before it optional, which in this case is the `. In a high-level, this means that the author of that code is allowing for $tablename *or* `$tablename`.

Note that the regular expression as stated also matches `$tablename and $tablename`, but such a case is probably very unlikely. One can modify it to exclude such cases by using [backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

```
m/DROP TABLE IF EXISTS (\`?)$tableName\1 || m/CREATE TABLE (\`?)$tableName\2/
```

Further reading on this operator can be found [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html).

Comment: So there isn't any special reason they are making them optional?

Comment: @Nate It is allowing escaped or non-escaped table names. I guess you could call that the special reason.